# CakePHP 3.x - Link and save associations with 3 models through one model

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0, entity-relationship, model-associations

I am using CakePHP version 3.x.

I need to link three models (*Trackers*, *Articles*, *Mentions*) through one Model (*TrackersArticlesMentions*).

Here my relations definition:

**TrackersTable.php**

```
    $this->belongsToMany('Mentions', [
        'through' => 'TrackersArticlesMentions',
        'saveStrategy' => 'append',
    ]);
    $this->belongsToMany('Articles', [
        'through' => 'TrackersArticlesMentions',
        'saveStrategy' => 'append',
    ]);
```

**ArticlesTable.php**

```
    $this->belongsToMany('Mentions', [
        'through' => 'TrackersArticlesMentions',
        'saveStrategy' => 'append',
    ]);
    $this->belongsToMany('Trackers', [
        'through' => 'TrackersArticlesMentions',
        'saveStrategy' => 'append',
    ]);
```

**MentionsTable.php**

```
    $this->belongsToMany('Articles', [
        'through' => 'TrackersArticlesMentions',
        'saveStrategy' => 'append',
    ]);
    $this->belongsToMany('Trackers', [
        'through' => 'TrackersArticlesMentions',
        'saveStrategy' => 'append',
    ]);
```

**TrackersArticlesMentionsTable.php**

```
    $this->belongsTo('Trackers', [
        'foreignKey' => 'tracker_id',
        'joinType' => 'INNER'
    ]);
    $this->belongsTo('Articles', [
        'foreignKey' => 'article_id',
        'joinType' => 'INNER'
    ]);
    $this->belongsTo('Mentions', [
        'foreignKey' => 'mention_id',
        'joinType' => 'INNER'
    ]);
```

So far everything is working perfectly when I want to find my data and include (aka contain) them.

Unfortunately, when I want to **link** them, I should be able to use the function link and do something like this:

```
$this->Trackers->link($trackerEntity, [$articleEntity, $mentionEntity]);
```

But it doesn't work, the function **link** expects as a second parameter:

> list of entities belonging to the `target` side of this association

I may be wrong, but the function seems to be made to link only two entities, the second parameter is only of an array of the same entity...

I found a solution by creating a function in the TrackersArticlesMentionsTable like this:

```
public function createLink(\App\Model\Entity\Tracker $trackerEntity, \App\Model\Entity\Article $articleEntity, \App\Model\Entity\Mention $mentionEntity)
{
    return $this->findOrCreate([
        'tracker_id' => $trackerEntity->get('id'),
        'article_id' => $articleEntity->get('id'),
        'mention_id' => $mentionEntity->get('id'),
    ]);
}
```

But I would like to do it "properly".
Does someone have any suggestion?
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `link()` method is ment to link a single association source side entity, to multiple (usually distinct) association target side entities, for example, link a single `Post` to multiple `Tag`s, which would be done via the `Tags` association.

So that means that via `$this->Trackers->link()` (I assume that `$this` is a table object, and therefore `$this->Trackers` is an association object), you could link a single `Mention` **or** `Article` to multiple (distinct) `Tracker`s.

The usage of `link()` that you have in mind is not supported, so you have to go with something like the solution that you came up with, eg create and save a `TrackersArticlesMention` entity on your own - it's perfectly fine to do that.